# SP2007: Specify image library for advanced search web control?

Tags: 2007, search

I'm having some issues setting up an advanced search for an image library.  Our advanced search web control resides on a separate page from the image library, so I need some way of telling the search to only search the image library.  I need to do the following:

1) Setup the advanced search to only query the image library (which resides on a separate page from the search, but within the same site)

2) The advanced search has a dropdown for fields to search by.  I need to populate this dropdown with all fields available from the image library.  Currently, it's not.

BUT...here's the catch...
For security reasons, we're restricted to only using "out of the box" solutions.  We can't create any custom webparts, use sharepoint designer, or change anything in sp central admin.

For example, I read one option was to create a search scope in central admin, but we don't have access to there, so that won't work.

Are there any ways to do this "out of the box"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the properties are available as Managed Properties, which can only be added through Central Admin the rest is pure configuration of the search page.

To limit the search to the Image library add "Site:URL_OF_LIBRARY" as Additional query terms (see [Configure properties for the Search Box Web Part (Office SharePoint Server 2007)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee329476%28v=office.12%29.aspx))

To add the fields follow [Steps to add properties to advanced search](http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2008/05/27/steps-to-add-properties-to-advanced-search/)